# Strange Unresolved External Symbol in C++/CLI

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have a LNK2001 error which I cannot solve!
My Solution is composed by a native project (DLL) and a managed one (DLL wrapper).
The native DLL works if is used with a native test application.
Now, the native code is the following (all defined into the namespace EuroSDK::Protocols) :

The EUROSDK_API is defined as __declspec(dllexport)

IMessageDispatcher.h

```
class EUROSDK_API IMessageDispatcher {
  public:

    IMessageDispatcher() : m_ProtocolAdapter(0) {};

    virtual ~IMessageDispatcher() {};

    virtual ERROR_CODE SendMessage(IMessage & msg) = 0;

    virtual ERROR_CODE SendMessage(IMessage & msg, STRING destination) { 
      RAISE_AND_RETURN(EC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED); 
    };

    virtual ERROR_CODE SendMessageSync(IMessage & msg) { 
      RAISE_AND_RETURN(EC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    };

    virtual ERROR_CODE SendMessageSync(IMessage & msg, IMessage & ret_msg) { 
      RAISE_AND_RETURN(EC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED); 
    };

    virtual ERROR_CODE SendMessageRaw(char* buff, UINT size) { 
      RAISE_AND_RETURN(EC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED); 
    };

    ERROR_CODE SetProtocolAdapter(IProtocolAdapter * adapter) {
      m_ProtocolAdapter = adapter;
      return EC_NO_ERRORS;
    }

  protected:
    IProtocolAdapter*   m_ProtocolAdapter;
};


class EUROSDK_API INetMessageDispatcher : public IMessageDispatcher {
  public:

    virtual ERROR_CODE Init(STRING  stationName, 
                            STRING  userName, 
                            BOOL    crypthData = FALSE) = 0;

    virtual ERROR_CODE Connect(UINT   portNumber, 
                               STRING remoteIP, 
                               UINT   connectionTimeOut = 5000) = 0;

    virtual ERROR_CODE Disconnect() = 0;
};
```

NetMessageDispatcher.h

```
class EUROSDK_API NetMessageDispatcher : public INetMessageDispatcher
{
  ...      
  ERROR_CODE  SendMessage(IMessage & msg);
  ERROR_CODE  SendMessage(IMessage & msg, STRING destination);    
  ...
};
```

NetMessageDispatcher.cpp

```
  ERROR_CODE  NetMessageDispatcher::SendMessage(IMessage & msg) {
     ... implementation ...
  }
  ERROR_CODE  NetMessageDispatcher::SendMessage(IMessage & msg, STRING destination) {
     ... implementation ...      
  }
```

Now, into the managed wrapper I have:

NetMessageDispatcherNET.h

```
using namespace EurocSDK::Protocols;

namespace EuroSDKNET {
  namespace Protocols {

    class NetMessageDispatcherWrap;

    public ref class NetMessageDispatcherNET {
      public:

        NetMessageDispatcherNET(EDispatcherType stationType, 
                                MessageEventHandlerNET^ handler)

        ~NetMessageDispatcherNET() {};

        // Implemented in the cpp file
        virtual int  SendMessage(IMessageNET^ msg);
        virtual int  SendMessage(IMessageNET^ msg, String^ destination);

        private:
        CAutoNativePtr<NetMessageDispatcherWrap> m_Dispatcher;
    };

    // Unmanaged Wrapper
    private class NetMessageDispatcherWrap : public ISessionFactory, 
                                             public NetMessageDispatcher {
      public:
        ~NetMessageDispatcherWrap() {}
        NetMessageDispatcherWrap(MessageEventHandlerNET^  handler,
                                 NetMessageDispatcherNET^ dispatcher,
                                 IMessageFactory::Ptr     messageFactory,                                 
                                 EuroSDKNET::Protocols::EDispatcherType stationType) : 
            NetMessageDispatcher(this, 
                                 messageFactory, 
                                 Logger::get("NetMessageDispatcher"), 
                                 (EuroSDK::Protocols::EDispatcherType)stationType),
            m_handler(handler),
            m_Dispatcher(dispatcher) {}

        /// Creates an instance of a Session,
        /// using the given message handler.
        inline Session* createSession(const IMessageDispatcher* dispatcher) {
          ..... implementation ....
        }

      private:
        gcroot<MessageEventHandlerNET^>   m_handler;
        gcroot<NetMessageDispatcherNET^>  m_Dispatcher;
    };    

  }
}
```

NetMessageDispatcherNET.cpp

```
NetMessageDispatcherNET::NetMessageDispatcherNET(EuroSDKNET::Protocols::EDispatcherType stationType, 
                                                 MessageEventHandlerNET^ handler) {

  m_Dispatcher = new NetMessageDispatcherWrap(handler,
                                              this,
                                              new EuroSDK::Protocols::PBMessageFactory(), 
                                              stationType);
}

NetMessageDispatcherNET::~NetMessageDispatcherNET() {}

int  NetMessageDispatcherNET::SendMessage(IMessageNET^ msg) {
  return 0;
}

int  NetMessageDispatcherNET::SendMessage(IMessageNET^ msg, String^ destination) {
  return 0;
}
```

Now, when I build the NET DLL I get:

```
1>NetMessageDispatcher.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (01000017) for 'boost.detail.win32._SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES'; image may not run
1>NetMessageDispatcherWrapper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual enum E_ErrorCode __thiscall EuroSDK::Protocols::NetMessageDispatcher::SendMessage(class EuroSDK::Protocols::IMessage &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?SendMessage@NetMessageDispatcher@Protocols@EuroSDK@@UAE?AW4E_ErrorCode@@AAVIMessage@23@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>NetMessageDispatcherWrapper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual enum E_ErrorCode __thiscall EuroSDK::Protocols::NetMessageDispatcher::SendMessage(class EuroSDK::Protocols::IMessage &)" (?SendMessage@NetMessageDispatcher@Protocols@EuroSDK@@UAE?AW4E_ErrorCode@@AAVIMessage@23@@Z)
```

What could cause the problem?

Daniele.

Comment: Do you compile it as 32 or 64 bit version? I have an assumption but please try to compile it as 32 bit first

Comment: Dis you add unmanaged .lib file to managed project linker dependencies?

Comment: Hi @VladL, I'm on 64 bit OS but I'm compiling it as 32 bit. Of course I add the .lib file into linker props. What I cannot understand is why only these two methods are unresolved!

Comment: @Barzo try adding `#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:SendMessage=_SendMessage@4")` right after all includes. Please tell me if it changes something

Comment: @VladL I made some tests and I found that if I comment the two declarations in the IMessageDispatcher interface, all build and link. This let me doubtful because those are implemented! Do you know what can cause this behavior?

Comment: @Barzo can you post your INetMessageDispatcher please?

Comment: Too many macros.  Use Dumpbin.exe to see what these exported functions actually look like.

Comment: @Barzo that was the missing part ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your new comments and your edit

in your `IMessageDispatcher` class you are defining

```
 virtual ERROR_CODE SendMessage(IMessage & msg) = 0;

 virtual ERROR_CODE SendMessage(IMessage & msg, STRING destination) { 
      RAISE_AND_RETURN(EC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED); 
    };
```

Now `INetMessageDispatcher` inherits those 2 functions from IMessageDispatcher which means they can be called on an INetMessageDispatcher instance after youi implement the pure virtual one.

Next, `NetMessageDispatcher` inherits those two functions from `INetMessageDispatcher` and that is a redefinition, so your solution is

1) either remove the redifinitions from the `NetMessageDispatcher` class, they are unnecessary

2) If you use C++ 11 you could use an `override` keyword

```
class EUROSDK_API NetMessageDispatcher : public INetMessageDispatcher
{
  ...      
  virtual ERROR_CODE SendMessage(IMessage & msg) override;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @VladL but I'm little confused. Ok, don't scold me but, if I remove the definitions from NetMessageDispatcher, how can I override them?

Comment: @Barzo try declaring them as virtual everywhere without to remove them

Comment: I have already tried. I also tried to make all method into the IMessageDispatcher pure virtual but with no success. What I don't understand is why if I use the native library with a native test project all works with no problems.